# NTP reach property equivalent for timedatectl command

Tags: linux, systemd, ntp, time-synchronization, systemd-timesyncd

The `ntpq -p` command returns information which includes the reach and when properties as shown in the example:

```
      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 10.3.1.01       .STEP.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
*10.1.1.01       121.158.3.212    2 u  743 1024  377   33.951   -0.448   1.796
```

Is there a command with timedatectl which can give me the information concerning these two properties? I tried getting the information from `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` but the information seems slightly different than what I was looking for.